# Java sort hashmap by double value not working

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I am trying to sort a hashmap containing an object and a double value but it's not working as expected. Here is my code.

```
HashMap<Route, Double> unsortedRoutes = new HashMap<>();

unsortedRoutes.add(new Route("Route Z"),9.49307305463114167);
unsortedRoutes.add(new Route("Route A"),9.546311415463114167);
unsortedRoutes.add(new Route("Route K"),9.37307305463114167);
unsortedRoutes.add(new Route("Route Y"),9.89730305463114167);
unsortedRoutes.add(new Route("Route Z"),3.49307305463114167);
unsortedRoutes.add(new Route("Route A"),3.41870305463114167);
unsortedRoutes.add(new Route("Route K"),4.49307305463114167);
unsortedRoutes.add(new Route("Route Y"),5.34307305463114167);

HashMap<Route, Double> sortedRoutes = new HashMap<>();
        unsortedRoutes.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(comparingByValue())
                .forEachOrdered(x -> sortedRoutes.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));
```

When I ran the code these are the results I get

```
Name: Route D Distance = 3.4187030546311417
Name: Route J Distance = 5.343073054631142
Name: Route A Distance = 9.546311415463114
Name: Route Y Distance = 9.897303054631141
Name: Route U Distance = 4.493073054631141
Name: Route K Distance = 9.373073054631142
Name: Route Z Distance = 9.493073054631141
Name: Route Q Distance = 3.4930730546311417
```

I expected the results to be listed in ascending order.

Comment: You don't sort a `HashMap`, because insertion order isn't guaranteed to be preserved, that's why it doesn't work. If you really need a map, you have to use a `TreeMap` with a custom `Comparator` instead.

Comment: Your `sortedRoute` should be a `LinkedHashMap`!

Comment: This sort of questions should be considered as blasphemy

Comment: HashMaps are by nature unsorted, and it makes no difference if you put in items in any particular order. If you need an ordered map then use an ordered map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashMap`s make no guarantee on the order of elements stored in them, so even if you call `put` in a sorted fashion, the resulting `HashMap` will have no intrinsic order. If you want to preserve the order that `put` was called in, you should use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

```
Map<Route, Double> sortedRoutes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Comment: @Nikolas you experienced a downvote of your upvote? IMHO this answer is fine, just altering the implementing map class.